# Code confusion while extending PHP exception class

Tags: php, exception

This question is related to extending the PHP exception class and there are many similar questions but this one is different.

I am trying to extend the PHP exception class so I can add certain values to the exception message. Below is my code.

```
class Om_Exception extends Exception {

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        $message = $this->_getMessage($message);
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    protected function _getMessage($message) {
        $exception = '<br />';
        $exception .= '<b>Exception  => </b>'.$message.'<br />';
        $exception .= '<b>Class => </b>'.get_called_class().'<br />';
        $exception .= '<b>Error Line => </b>'.$this->getLine().'<br />';
        $exception .= '<b>Error File => </b>'.$this->getFile().'<br />';
        return $exception;
    }

}
```

This works fine. And that is my problem.

Since I am calling the functions `getLine()` and `getFile()` of the parent class before calling its constructor shouldn't they return blank values? if not error?

But this works fine and I get the output described below.

```
Exception => hello..
Class => Om_Controller_Exception
Error Line => 30
Error File => C:\Users\Jay\Projects\order-manager\application\modules\default\controllers\LoginController.php
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this behavior? How can I use class methods before initializing the class?

Comment: What do you mean "before calling it's constructor"? Your class has constructor and it explicitly calls parent constructor

Comment: @AlmaDo Before the parent constructor is called _getMessage() method is called which calls getLine() and getFile() methods of parent class.

Comment: So what? Your methods would be inherited and their implementation as well. Thus, your call will use standard `Exception` methods

Comment: constructor initialize properties, not methods. You can call any method before parent constructor unless it don't use uninitialized properties

Comment: `Exception` is a special built-in class in PHP. The `$code`, `$file` and `$line` properties are populated before the constructor is executed.

Comment: @silkfire Thanks a lot. This makes sense and this was the answer I was looking for. Can you please post this in answer?

Comment: @JayBhatt I'd rather not. It's common sense and pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called ***on a newly created object***, so the object and all it's properties and methods already exists when the constructor is called. This example should make it pretty clear:

```
<?php

class testParent {
    protected $protectedStuff = 1;
    public function __construct($intNumber) {
        $this->protectedStuff = $intNumber;
    }
}
class testChild extends testParent {
    public function __construct($intNumber) {
        echo get_class() . '<br />'; // testChild
        echo get_parent_class() . '<br />'; // testParent
        $this->printStuff(); // 1
        parent::__construct($intNumber);
        $this->printStuff(); // 42
    }
    public function printStuff() {
        echo '<br />The number is now: ' . $this->protectedStuff;
    }
}
$objChild = new testChild(42);
```

Result

> testChild
>
> testParent
>
> The number is now: 1
>
> The number is now: 42